# Obtaining a function from the function

Tags: functions

Assume that;

```
w[n_] :=Expand[Sum[Binomial[n - k - 1, k]*(-1)^k*A^(n - 2*k - 1), {k, 0, n - 1}]]
f[x_,y_, z_]:=PolynomialRemainder[(w[z] - 1)*(w[y] - 1), (w[x] - 1), A]
```

According to the above definitions, the function `f` depends on `x,y,z` and `A`. I want to have a new function only depends on `A` for any `x,y,z`. For example, when i put some values for `x,y,z`, i want a function such

`g[A_]:=.........`How can i obtain?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := 
   Block[{A}, 
     Function @@ {A,PolynomialRemainder[(w[z] - 1)*(w[y] - 1), (w[x] - 1), A]}
   ]
```

When you call `f`, the result would be a pure function depending on `A` only, with the values `x`, `y` and `z` embedded into its body. I used `Function @@ {}` idiom to allow the body to evaluate, so that the evaluation of `PolynomialRemainder` and `w` is done only once, at definition-time.

For example:

```
f[4, 5, 16]

(* Function[A, 4 + 2 A - 2 A^2] *)
```

and you can now store this function in a variable and apply it many times. Technically, what you asked for is how one can create a closure - a function which carries some of the surrounding environment in its body. In this case, it was a little more tricky since I chose to perform some evaluation at definition-time as an optimization.

As a side note, it is best to not use capital letters for variables, since names starting with capital letters may collide with the system names.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the case `x=4`, `y=5`, `z=16` and in order to obtain a list for `0<A<10`, what will i do?

Comment: @Nurettinırmak `myFun = f[4, 5, 16]; Map[myFun, Range[9]]`.

Comment: Thank you. i am new user. Therefore, i can ask very easy questions :)

Comment: @Nurettinırmak Glad I could help, and thanks for the accept. I would still suggest to spend some time and get familiar with the basics. The question you asked was not quite a basic one, so this does not apply to the case at hand, but be aware that very basic (RTFM - like) questions are frowned upon here.

Comment: +1 Leonid: Another "easy" question from the OP for you to enjoy http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22807/193